# SQL Nested /Sub-query and SQL produce the same result. Why using Nested/Sub-Query?

Tags: sql, subquery

I don't understand why the solution gives me a nested solution when I can get the same result with non-nested SQL stmt. Is it better to use Nested SQL ? Thanks !

Here is the code :

SQL :

```
select EMP_ID, F_NAME, L_NAME, DEP_ID from employees;
```

SQL Nested/Sub-Query solution :

```
select * from ( select EMP_ID, F_NAME, L_NAME, DEP_ID from employees) AS EMP4ALL;
```

Comment: Welcome to stack-overflow .... your question not enough quality but you can edit to better, please read help center, section `how to ask good question` here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and you can get tour here https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query optimser of whichever platform you use will almost certainly parse these to be identical and produce the same execution plan for each.

In short, they are the same; the *derived table* query may be a cut-down version of something more complex and the author just chose to leave it that way, unknown really without more context.